# How to log into lxc container?

Tags: lxc

I recently installed the 32 bit lxc container on a 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 system.
When I run the command `sudo lxc-start -n my32bitbox` I am greeted with a login prompt. I
enter the default login and password which is: login= ubuntu ; password= ubuntu; but I am still unable to log on to the container. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does authentication log file of the container show any login fail? See `/var/lib/lxc/my32bitbox/rootfs/var/log/auth.log` after login try. (Use appropriate container's rootfs address if you haven't created the container in the defualt path)

Answer (score 16):

login to container

```
lxc exec <container-name> -- sudo --login --user <username>
```

get the shell prompt of the container

```
lxc exec <container-name> -- sudo /bin/bash
```

Comment: This answer assumes lxd, not lxc.

Answer (score 3):

```
lxc-start -n <container_name> -d
lxc-attach -n <container_name>
```

does the trick

Answer (score 2):

You can also use ssh command to login to LXC-container:

```
ssh lxcuser@container_ip_address
```

To find out the LXC IP-address you can use this:

```
ssh ubuntu@`sudo lxc-info -iH -n CN`
```

where CN is the container name and 'ubuntu' is the user acc in the LXC.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enter the password for the "sudo" command to gain root privilege, in order to run lxc-start. It is not the login prompt for the container itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
lxc exec <container> passwd
```

set your passwd
exit out (ctrl-a q)

then

```
lxc console <container>
```

Comment: This answer assumes lxd, not lxc.